# Cannot upload image using IKUpload in imagekitio-react v2.0.0 in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

i'm using library imagekitio-react v2.0.0 and component IKUpload to upload file.
This show the error[image] and i don't know where is my issue. I'm do all the guides of https://docs.imagekit.io/getting-started/quickstart-guides/react but it still.
Any one can help me, i stuck with this too long. Many thanks